# Generating NXN spirals

Tags: python

I have been given the task of creating a spiral in python where the user inputs a number e.g 3 and it will output a 3x3 spiral which looks like this:

```
- - \
/ \ |
\ - /
```

**I am not looking for the full code** I just have no idea how to do it, obviously printing out every possible solution using if statements isn't possible or logical. The real question here is what should i be looking to do, for loops, define my own function? are there any docs people can link me to that would help. The full task outline is as follows:

> Your task here is to write a program to draw a spiral of a given size
>   inside a box.
>
> Your program should ask the user for a positive integer denoting the size of the box. Your program should then print out a
>   spiral inside of a box of that size.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> Enter size: 3
> - - \
> / \ |
> \ - /
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> Enter size: 4
> - - - \
> / - \ |
> | \ / |
> \ - - /
> ```
>
> ​and:
>
> ```
> Enter size: 5     
> - - - - \
> / - - \ |
> | / \ | |
> | \ - / |
> \ - - - /
> ```
>
> The input size will always be greater than 1.

Comment: Try with at least something. Try to produce a line and a corner. Play around with params.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I respect you for not wanting the full code. This is intentionally only a partial answer.

Start by making a 2-dimensional array. Something like:

```
grid = [[None]*n for i in range(n)]
```

This allows you to write code like `grid[i][j] = '\'`.

Start with `i,j = 0,0`. In a loop spiral around the grid. It might help to have a variable `direction` which takes on values `'right', 'left', 'up', 'down'` together with a corresponding `delta` taking on values like `(0,1)` (for moving to the right) to be added to `(i,j)` to implement the move.

Go along a line in a certain direction placing '-' or '|' until you hit a corner (check for `None` as well as the limits of the overall grid). When you get to a corner, place the appropriate corner marker and change directions.

Once the grid is filled, join each rows with an empty string delimiter and join the result with `'\n'` as the delimiter.

Answer (score 14):

Things to note:

- number of characters in rows/cols is **n**
- first row will always have **n - 1** `-`s and one `\`
- last row will always have **n - 2** `-`s, begin with `\` and ends with `/`

For example, when `n` is 4:

First row: `- - - \`
Last row: `\ - - /`

Can be easily achieved using:

```
def get_first_raw(n):
    return '- ' * (n - 1) + '\\'

def get_last_raw(n):
    return '\\ ' + '- ' * (n - 2) + '/'
```

Now regarding the body of the spiral, note the following:

For n = 3:

```
- - \
/ \ |
\ - /
```

For n = 5:

[image]

For n = 6:

[image]

Note that the 4-spiral is **contained** inside it, and the red boxes are **fixed**. Only their length changes according to **n**.

It's contained inside it. And fore **n = 7**, the **n = 5** is contained inside it. The same holds for **n = 2k**, each n will have **n/2** spiral contained in it.

What I'm trying to say here that you manually draw **n = 3** and **n = 2**. If the spiral should be made from an even number, you use the **n = 2** pattern, construct the first and last rows, and using loops you can append the body of the spiral.

Example for **n = 5**:

```
def get_spiral(n):
    res = []
    res.append(get_first_raw(n))
    res.append('/ ' + spiral[0] + ' |')
    for line in spiral[1:]:
        res.append('| ' + line + ' |')

    res.append(get_last_raw(n))
    return res

print '\n'.join(get_spiral(5))
```

where `spiral` is an initial spiral of size 3:

```
spiral = ['- - \\', '/ \ |', '\ - /']
```

In order to generate 7-spiral, you do:

```
spiral = build_spiral(5)
print '\n'.join(build_spiral(7))
```

and you'll get:

```
- - - - - - \
/ - - - - \ |
| / - - \ | |
| | / \ | | |
| | \ - / | |
| \ - - - / |
\ - - - - - /
```

Of course this can be improved and you can make the program more efficient, I just wanted to give you a guideline and to share my thoughts..

Here's more spirals for fun:

```
- - - - - - - - - - \
/ - - - - - - - - \ |
| / - - - - - - \ | |
| | / - - - - \ | | |
| | | / - - \ | | | |
| | | | / \ | | | | |
| | | | \ - / | | | |
| | | \ - - - / | | |
| | \ - - - - - / | |
| \ - - - - - - - / |
\ - - - - - - - - - /
```

---

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \
/ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \ |
| / - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \ | |
| | / - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \ | | |
| | | / - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \ | | | |
| | | | / - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \ | | | | |
| | | | | / - - - - - - - - - - - - \ | | | | | |
| | | | | | / - - - - - - - - - - \ | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | / - - - - - - - - \ | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | / - - - - - - \ | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | / - - - - \ | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | / - - \ | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | / \ | | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | | \ - / | | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | | \ - - - / | | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | | \ - - - - - / | | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | | \ - - - - - - - / | | | | | | | |
| | | | | | | \ - - - - - - - - - / | | | | | | |
| | | | | | \ - - - - - - - - - - - / | | | | | |
| | | | | \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - / | | | | |
| | | | \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - / | | | |
| | | \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - / | | |
| | \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - / | |
| \ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - / |
\ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - /
```

<sup>You also got a top view for a pyramid for free</sup>

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
def rot_right(a):
    return zip(*a[::-1])


def spiral(m, n, start=1, is_rotate=False):
    if n < 1:
        return

    lst = ['|' if is_rotate else '-' for i in range(start, m + start - 1)]
    lst += ['/' if is_rotate and m > 0 else '\\']


    yield tuple(lst)
    for row in rot_right(list(spiral(n - 1, m, m + start, not is_rotate))):
        yield row

n = 7
for row in spiral(n, n):
    print(''.join('%s' % i for i in row))
```

result:

```
------\
/----\|
|/--\||
||/\|||
||\-/||
|\---/|
\-----/

-------\
/-----\|
|/---\||
||/-\|||
|||\/|||
||\--/||
|\----/|
\------/
```

Comment: Hm, this generates the middle bit facing the wrong way, how would you fix that?

Comment: fixed, you can try to use

Answer (score 1):

As there are already some good answers with how to do it, I went along with the way I like and made the code, which is travelling in the spiral order and go setting the characters along the way. Its a bit long but for understanding purposes, could be shortened down about half:

```
n = 3;

grid = [[None]*n for i in range(n)]


def move(pos, d, counter): # first paint, then move
    x = pos[0]
    y=pos[1]

    #uncomment this line to check how it moves
    #print (x,y)

    if d == "right":
        if x == n-y-1: # if we are going right and we reach the end(n-y) -1 because of indexes, change direction to down
            grid[y][x] = "\\"
            y+=1
            d = "down"
        else:
            grid[y][x] = "-"
            x+=1
    elif d == "down": # if we are going down and reach the end, which is the same as column number we are on, change direction to left
        if y == x:
            grid[y][x] = "/"
            x-=1
            d = "left"
        else:
            grid[y][x] = "|"
            y+=1
    elif d == "left": # if we are going left and reach the end, which is the same as in right, change directiont to up
        if x == n-y-1:
            grid[y][x] = "\\"
            y-=1
            d="up"
        else:
            grid[y][x] = "-"
            x-=1
    elif d == "up": # if we are going up and reach the end, which is x+1, change direction to right
        if y ==x+1:
            grid[y][x] = "/"
            x+=1
            d = "right"
        else:
            grid[y][x] = "|"
            y-=1

    counter+=1
    if counter != n*n: # if we painted n*n times, it means we finished with the spiral
        move((x,y),d,counter)


move((0,0),"right",0) # start in coords (0,0) with direction going right and counter in 0

for row in grid:
    print(''.join('%s' % i for i in row))
```

Comment: So in the spirals i'm meant to output there's a space between each one like shown above. This is achieved by putting a space next to each character, but say i put that space on the right then every single line will have a space on the right even if it is invisible, is there a way to maybe .rstrip() or something?

Comment: Fixed! added a space to the right of each character (-, / , \\) and then on the print at the end make it .... print(''.join('%s' % i for i in row).rstrip(' '))

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, but as the larger values of n are used to create the spiral, it becomes apparent that the spiral is a system of 3 equations and their inequalities. There are three line equations that correspond to the usage of `\` and `/`:

```
\ is y1 = -x + (n - 1)
/ is y2 = x + 1
     y3 = x

 0,0
  - - - - - - - \y1
y2/ - - - - - \ |
  | / - - - \ | |
  | | / - \ | | |
  | | | \ / | | |
  | | \ - - / | |
  | \ - - - - / |
  \ - - - - - - /y3
```

Then, going through all points in the grid, calculate y1, y2 and y3 for the given x. Output the correct character given the current value of y in comparison to y1, y2 and y3.

If it's on a line, then it's a `\` or `/`. If it's below both y1 and y2 or above both y1 and y3, then it's `-`, otherwise it's a `|` *(C# Example)*:

```
for (int y = 0; y < n; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
    {
        string c = "  ";
        int y1 = (n - 1) + (-1 * x);
        int y2 = x + 1;
        int y3 = x; // Redundant

        if (y == y1)
            c = "\\ ";
        else if ((y <= n / 2 && y == y2) || (y >= n / 2 && y == y3))
            c = "/ ";
        else if (y < y1 && y < y2)
            c = "- ";
        else if (y > y1 && y > y3)
            c = "- ";
        else
            c = "| ";

        Console.Write(c);
    }
    Console.Write('\n');
}
```